# Check multiple case expressions result at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have a case expression inside an aggregate function in a select statement that looks something like this.

```
select person_id,
    sum(case status = 'approved' then hours else 0.0 end) as hours
    sum(case status = 'cancelled' then void_hrs else 0.0 end) as void_hrs
    sum(case status = 'forwarded' then fwd_hrs else 0.0 end) as fwd_hrs
from table
```

Now, how do I check if all of the cases returns 0.0? So that I can exclude it on the result set?

Comment: It might "look" like this but it also must be very different because what you provided has syntax errors and won't even compile. And you could have just copied the code given to you in your previous question. Just not trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a `where` clause:

```
select person_id,
       sum(case status = 'approved' then hours else 0.0 end) as hours
       sum(case status = 'cancelled' then void_hrs else 0.0 end) as void_hrs
       sum(case status = 'forwarded' then fwd_hrs else 0.0 end) as fwd_hrs
from table
where status in ('approved', 'cancelled', 'forwarded')
group by person_id;
```

As a bonus, this might improve performance if you have a lot of rows with other statuses.

Alternatively, you can add a `having` clause to your query:

```
having sum(case when status in ('approved', 'cancelled', 'forwarded') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is probably to turn your query to a subquery, then filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select person_id,
        sum(case status = 'approved' then hours else 0.0 end) as hours
        sum(case status = 'cancelled' then void_hrs else 0.0 end) as void_hrs
        sum(case status = 'forwarded' then fwd_hrs else 0.0 end) as fwd_hrs
    from mytable
    group by person_id
) t
where hours + void_hrs + fwd_hrs > 0
```

Note that your original query was missing a `group by` clause, I added that.

The alternative would be to use a lengthy `having` clause:

```
select person_id,
    sum(case status = 'approved' then hours else 0.0 end) as hours
    sum(case status = 'cancelled' then void_hrs else 0.0 end) as void_hrs
    sum(case status = 'forwarded' then fwd_hrs else 0.0 end) as fwd_hrs
from mytable
group by person_id
having sum(
    case status 
        when 'approved' then hours
        when 'cancelled' then void_hrs
        when 'forwarded' then fwd_hrs
        else 0.0
    end
) > 0
```

Side note: this is called a `case` *expression*, not a case *statement*. The latter is a flow control structure, while the former is conditional logic.